# ROS2 foxy on Yocto 3 (zeus)

Tags: ros, ros2

I have an image built using Yocto. The version is 3.0 (zeus) and unfortunately I can't change/upgrade it since that come from the board supplier. So I've cloned the zeus branch:

`git clone --single-branch --branch zeus https://github.com/ros/meta-ros.git`

and added the layer to bblayrs.conf:

`BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-ros/meta-ros2-foxy"`

Unfortunately the build failed with error:

> ERROR: Layer ros2-foxy-layer is not compatible with the core layer
> which only supports these series: zeus

What did I wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `ROS_OE_RELEASE_SERIES = "zeus"` to ${BUILDDIR}/conf/bblayers.conf file.